# Pandas - Selecting all columns but one in DataFrame while setting dtype

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to do something using Pandas that seems to be quite difficult. I hope I'm wrong

I want to open a csv-file, set the dtype of every column as int with the exception of one column that I would like to drop. 
I do not now the names and/or the number of columns present in advance.
The non-int column is *always* present at the same position, every other column consits only of intergers.

data:

```
foo.csv:
a   b       c   d   e   f  g ...
1   700592  a   23 ... ... ...
2   808295  b   24 ... ...
3   106796  c   25 ...
4   166438  d   26 ...
5   172594  e   27 ...
```

what I would like to do:

```
df = pd.read_csv(foo.csv, usecols=[0,1,3, ...], dtype=int)
```

I could read the complete file, drop the non-int column, and change the type globally but the data may be very large so speed and memory are to be considered.

Answer (score 0):

Before passing to pandas use `np.loadtxt()`:

`import numpy as np
f = np.loadtxt("foo.csv", usecols=[0,1,2,4], dtype="int32")
pd.DataFrame(f)`

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html